# Compare percentage value against decimal Excel

Tags: excel, formula

I am a bit stumped with this issue, I was wondering if anyone could suggest a solution. In Excel I have a table which looks like this:

```
1   2   3   4   5   Result  Score
80% 85% 90% 95% 100%    92.5%   3.50
```

What I am trying to calculate is that proportional score, based on where the result falls within the preset decimal 1-5 score.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your case where each increment is 5% you could use a simple calculation like

`=MAX(0,F2-75%)*20`

[where result is in F2]

....but assuming that you want to interpolate the score given potentially less linear values in your table try this formula where your table is in A1:E2

`=LOOKUP(F2,A2:E2,A1:E1+(F2-A2:D2)*(B1:E1-A1:D1)/(B2:E2-A2:D2))`

Comment: The interpolated forumla works really well thanks. The only issue is that if you have a score below the defined threshold it #n/a's.

Comment: You can add an IF to give zero if F2 < A2, i.e. `=IF(F2<A2,0,LOOKUP(F2,A2:E2,A1:E1+(F2-A2:D2)*(B1:E1-A1:D1)/(B2:E2-A2:D2)))`

Answer (score 0):

for linear interpolation this would be general formula, just name the ranges or replace with cell references:

```
= (perc - minperc) / (maxperc - minperc) * (maxscore - minscore) + minscore
```